# How I can trigger a Lambda function each time I update AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I'm using AWS Secrets Manager, and I have also a Lambda function.

How do I trigger my Lambda function each time I add/edit/delete (update) a secret in AWS Secrets Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All SecretsManager operations are [logged](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudtrail.html) with CloudTrail.
2. [Match](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/monitoring-eventbridge.html) these events with EventBridge.
3. Set up the lambda as a [target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html) for the EventBridge rule.

Comment: can you explain more please ( steps ) thank you

Comment: @DockerIssues: more how? I will not implement it for you, but if you have a concrete question about any of these steps I'll be happy to answer. Are you familiar with all pieces of this setup?

Comment: I went to CloudTrail, and I don't have a trail yet . should i create one ? what should i do from there. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @DockerIssues: there should be default trail for management events, one per account. If it's missing, create it (only check management events). If it warns you that it will charge you because you're logging it more than in one trail, then look better for the default one.

Comment: First thank you so much for the help .
I followed the steps and i created event by adding my seret ARN .
I changed the secrets in my secret manager . but the function is not triggered

Comment: @DockerIssues: probably it counts as a data plane event. Try adding data plane events to your trail and select `UpdateSecret` or something like that in the filter. I'm not able to use the console now.

Comment: It's working Thank you so much so much

Comment: @DockerIssues Can you please explain how you get it working? I am having the same issue and the lambda is not getting triggered even if the cloudtrail logs the PutSecretValue.